# How can I use a single Hebrew letter or glyph in (La)TeX?

Tags: symbols, hebrew

[image]

How to insert only the symbol "tav" (Hebrew) in (la)tex?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `cjhebrew` package and add in the source file the following :
`\cjRL{t}`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}

\begin{document}
Some text, a hebrew charcacter: \cjRL{t}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  In particular a good answer often includes a short complete compilable example document.

Comment: It would be nice if you could enlarge the image of the output a bit, it's kind of small.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Benedikt Bauer and user48527

Just for sharing I could also solve it as follows,
with `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Then, within the document we can put

```
\scalebox{1}{\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{tav.jpg}}
```

Obviously you have to have the tav.jpg file in an appropriate directory and you can so put the glyph in a text line.